# How to pass data with Laravel blade components with Alpine.js in a stepped form

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I have the following models and relationships established **User**, **Vehicle**, **Action**, **ActionType**
my form route is '/actions/create'

I am attempting to create a stepped form where page 1 you select

- an action type from a drop down
- a vehicle from a drop down
- hit *continue*

=> this will store the action to the database (this works now) and returns

```
 return response()->json(["action" => $action, "vehicle" => $vehicle]);
//which is accessible to my alpine object as "action" and "vehicle"
```

Step 2 of the form I want it to open my existing vehicles.edit form and allow the user to modify the Vehicle Model and hit *save* which goes on to additional steps that access other edit model forms.

my issue is the server-side php and client-side alpine.js and how to get the data to the right model in the right place

Once i get to step 2 i think i can figure the rest out.

```
<div x-data="{
    step: {{ session('step') ?? 1 }},
    action:{},
    vehicle:{},
    async storeAction(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.step++;
        body = new FormData(actionForm)
        const response = await fetch(actionForm.action, {
            method: actionForm.method,
            body: new FormData(actionForm)
        });
        const result = await response.json();
        this.action = result.action;
        this.vehicle= result.vehicle;
    } 
}">
<div x-show="step ===1">
    <form id="action-form" action="/actions" method="POST" 
        x-data="{actions:{{ $actionTypes }},message:'',vehicle:{}}">
      input fields...
      <x-theme-button class="my-4" class="next" @click="storeAction">Continue</x-theme-button>
</div>
{{-- ======================   step 2    ====================== --}}
<div x-show="step ===2">  
    <div id="action-result"></div>              
    show this on step <span x-text="step"></span> 
    {{-- this is where I am having issue. i have tried ::, : just 'vehicle' --}}
    <x-forms.vehicles.edit ::vehicle="vehicle" ::action="action" />
    <x-theme-button @click="step++">Continue</x-theme-button>
</div>
<script>
  const actionForm = document.getElementById('action-form');
  const actionNextButton = actionForm.querySelector('.next')
  const actionResult = document.getElementById('action-result');
</script>
```

I receive the json object after the action creation but am not sure how to communicate it my alpine and blade components

Comment: I am starting to think this might be better to create a new controller function for each step. then the formRequest can redirect back without having to parse json responses and i don't have to fight server/client side restrictions

Comment: To be honest, this is a perfect use case for using Livewire. Any reasons you want to avoid using that?

Comment: I think you should post your `forms.vehicles.edit` component

Comment: just not familiar with livewire yet

Comment: Update so i just read about livewire and I am in. where has this been all my life:)